# Writing nice receipt in C# WPF for printing on thermal printer POS

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to implement print functionality on one of my project but I am not so good in this kind of work.

I already have connected with my thermal printer and write/print same samples.
Now I am trying to find some way to design my receipt to look like receipt from attached image.

I have some ideas but I am not sure if they are good for this kind of work, one of them is to try to format my receipt in html and their render html like bitmap(image) and then print it, I already tried this but it looks like I have an loss of quality.

If somebody have any other ideas about how I can make receipt look like on from the image please share this info with me I will be very thankful.

This is what I already did to print some samples, for formatting I used   `graphics.DrawString` but I don't think that I can accomplish too much using it.

```
public void Print()
{
    var doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(ProvideContent);
    doc.Print();
}

public void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10);

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

    int startX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int Offset = 20;

    e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 50;
    graphics.DrawString("Welcome to MSST", new Font("Courier New", 8),
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;

    graphics.DrawString("Ticket No:" + "4525554654545",
                new Font("Courier New", 14),
                new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;


    graphics.DrawString("Ticket Date :" + "21/12/215",
                new Font("Courier New", 14),
                new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);

    Offset = Offset + 20;
    String underLine = "------------------------------------------";

    graphics.DrawString(underLine, new Font("Courier New", 14),
                new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);

    Offset = Offset + 20;
    String Grosstotal = "Total Amount to Pay = " + "2566";

    Offset = Offset + 20;
    underLine = "------------------------------------------";
    graphics.DrawString(underLine, new Font("Courier New", 14),
                new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
    Offset = Offset + 20;

    graphics.DrawString(Grosstotal, new Font("Courier New", 14),
                new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);

}
```

[image]

Comment: An answer for this could take some time, and assuming you'd just be calling [PrintDialog.Print](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) you can do this pretty painlessly.  In short, you'd create your own DocumentPaginator.  The overrode print function would create a UserControl for the receipt and you'd set the DataContext of the print control to some sort of ReceiptViewModel.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the past when doing this I split up the receipt into separate parts that used different fonts or alignments such as Header, Body, Footer.

I used the following class layout to encapsulate my printed text definition.
(where you get the Font from and how you manage its lifetime is up to you)

```cs
public class PrintText
{
    public PrintText(string text, Font font) : this(text, font, new StringFormat()) {}

    public PrintText(string text, Font font, StringFormat stringFormat)
    {
        Text = text;
        Font = font;
        StringFormat = stringFormat;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Font Font { get; set; }

    /// <summary> Default is horizontal string formatting </summary>
    public StringFormat StringFormat { get; set; }
}
```

When there are longer lists of texts using the same font & padding then using a stringbuilder to build up your text makes life easy so you get a visual of how it will look just from inspecting your code.

If you had static text you can fit it all together as so:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Start of receipt");
sb.AppendLine("================");
sb.AppendLine("Item 1");
sb.AppendLine("Item 2");
sb.AppendLine("================");
```

Or if the data is a bit dynamic pass in some object you can iterate over and append your formatted text:

```cs
private class ReceiptItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int Discount { get; set; }

    public decimal Total { get { return Cost * Amount; } }
}
```

```cs
const int FIRST_COL_PAD = 20;
const int SECOND_COL_PAD = 7;
const int THIRD_COL_PAD = 20;

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Start of receipt");
sb.AppendLine("================");

foreach (var item in receiptItems)
{
    sb.Append(item.Name.PadRight(FIRST_COL_PAD));

    var breakDown = item.Amount > 0 ? item.Amount + "x" + item.Cost : string.Empty;
    sb.Append(breakDown.PadRight(SECOND_COL_PAD));

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0:0.00} A", item.Total).PadLeft(THIRD_COL_PAD));

    if (item.Discount > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("DISCOUNT {0:D2}%", item.Discount).PadRight(FIRST_COL_PAD + SECOND_COL_PAD));
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0:0.00} A", -(item.Total / 100 * item.Discount)).PadLeft(THIRD_COL_PAD));
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
}

sb.AppendLine("================");
```

The output will look like:

```
Start of receipt
================
Joes Food           1x10      10.00 A
DISCOUNT 10%                  -1.00 A
Fun Facts           1x20      20.00 A
DISCOUNT 15%                  -3.00 A
Bag of Sand         7x40     280.00 A
================
```

Using the PrintText class earlier we can store our nicely formatted string builder output

```
var printText = new PrintText(sb.ToString(), new Font("Monospace Please...", 8));
```

Then finally use that when attempting to draw the string

```
var layoutArea = new SizeF(AvailableWidth, 0);
SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(printText.Text, printText.Font, layoutArea, printText.StringFormat);

RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(new PointF(), new SizeF(AvailableWidth, stringSize.Height));

g.DrawString(printText.Text, printText.Font, Brushes.Black, rectf, printText.StringFormat);
```

You can also play around with a few different graphical tweaks if the text doesn't print quite right such as:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Comment: Amazing, is it possible to print the image generated to a receipt printer?

Comment: Sorry where can I download Monospace Please... font?

Comment: That's not a real font. I was just stating that the font you use when printing receipt items should be monospace/fixed width font so the text and numbers/prices align properly.

Comment: This solution always stops printing when the page size exceeds a4. Setting the page size to a roll, or 1000's of CM long does not help. It's like the windows print driver always takes over with paging? Toss a 1000 salesitems on your receipt and you will see what I mean

Comment: @clamchoda The thermal printer I was using at the time with this had a maximum buffer size so when I detected anything bigger than that I cut it into small chunks and sent 1 chunk at a time. That's all up to the printer you're using.

We were able to print multiple meters using the above, check the limit on your printer for how much data it can accept at one time.

Comment: I have also tried doing this. But can not get around the fact that after PrintPages event completes windows always sends a page feed command as if it was a regular printer. This is what causes the issue. No matter what you do, you can lie can dynamically increase the page height in the codebehind, but the event always sends that command :( (to the TMT 88IV anyways)

Comment: Hi, for the last few days I had same problem but your answer helped me a lot to get understanding of how to print receipts on thermal printer. I have only on query, does this solution works on any thermal printer. I am a newbie in C# .net so my clients demand receipts on thermal printer and I have no clue for printing :)

Comment: what do we do if item name is a really long string?

Comment: I mearnt - How can we go to next line if the string is longer than length

Answer (score 4):

I have designed a simple and smooth receipt design, i hope it will help you.

```
public class PrintJob
{
    private PrintDocument PrintDocument;
    private Graphics graphics;
    private Order order { set; get; }
    private Shop shop { set; get; }
    private int InitialHeight = 360;
    public PrintJob(Order order, Shop shop)
    {
        this.order = order;
        this.shop = shop;
        AdjustHeight();
    }
    private void AdjustHeight()
    {
        var capacity = 5 * order.ItemTransactions.Capacity;
        InitialHeight += capacity;

        capacity = 5 * order.DealTransactions.Capacity;
        InitialHeight += capacity;
    }
    public void Print(string printername)
    {
        PrintDocument = new PrintDocument();
        PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printername;

        PrintDocument.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(FormatPage);
        PrintDocument.Print();
    }
    void DrawAtStart(string text, int Offset)
    {
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 5;
        Font minifont = new Font("Arial", 5);

        graphics.DrawString(text, minifont,
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 5, startY + Offset);
    }
    void InsertItem(string key, string value, int Offset)
    {
        Font minifont = new Font("Arial", 5);
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 5;

        graphics.DrawString(key, minifont,
                     new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 5, startY + Offset);

        graphics.DrawString(value, minifont,
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 130, startY + Offset);
    }
    void InsertHeaderStyleItem(string key, string value, int Offset)
    {
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 5;
        Font itemfont = new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Bold);

        graphics.DrawString(key, itemfont,
                     new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 5, startY + Offset);

        graphics.DrawString(value, itemfont,
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 130, startY + Offset);
    }
    void DrawLine(string text, Font font, int Offset, int xOffset)
    {
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 5;
        graphics.DrawString(text, font,
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + xOffset, startY + Offset);
    }
    void DrawSimpleString(string text, Font font, int Offset, int xOffset)
    {
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 5;
        graphics.DrawString(text, font,
                 new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + xOffset, startY + Offset);
    }
    private void FormatPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        graphics = e.Graphics;
        Font minifont = new Font("Arial", 5);
        Font itemfont = new Font("Arial", 6);
        Font smallfont = new Font("Arial", 8);
        Font mediumfont = new Font("Arial", 10);
        Font largefont = new Font("Arial", 12);
        int Offset = 10;
        int smallinc = 10, mediuminc = 12, largeinc = 15;

        //Image image = Resources.logo;
        //e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, startX + 50, startY + Offset, 100, 30);

        //graphics.DrawString("Welcome to HOT AND CRISPY", smallfont,
        //      new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 22, startY + Offset);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc + 10;

        String underLine = "-------------------------------------";
        DrawLine(underLine, largefont, Offset, 0);

        Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
        DrawAtStart("Invoice Number: " + order.Invoice, Offset);

        if (!String.Equals(order.Customer.Address, "N/A"))
        {
            Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
            DrawAtStart("Address: " + order.Customer.Address, Offset);
        }

        if (!String.Equals(order.Customer.Phone, "N/A"))
        {
            Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
            DrawAtStart("Phone # : " + order.Customer.Phone, Offset);
        }

        Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
        DrawAtStart("Date: " + order.Date, Offset);

        Offset = Offset + smallinc;
        underLine = "-------------------------";
        DrawLine(underLine, largefont, Offset, 30);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc;

        InsertHeaderStyleItem("Name. ", "Price. ", Offset);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc;
        foreach (var itran in order.ItemTransactions)
        {
            InsertItem(itran.Item.Name + " x " + itran.Quantity, itran.Total.CValue, Offset);
            Offset = Offset + smallinc;
        }
        foreach (var dtran in order.DealTransactions)
        {
            InsertItem(dtran.Deal.Name, dtran.Total.CValue, Offset);
            Offset = Offset + smallinc;

            foreach (var di in dtran.Deal.DealItems)
            {
                InsertItem(di.Item.Name + " x " + (dtran.Quantity * di.Quantity), "", Offset);
                Offset = Offset + smallinc;
            }
        }

        underLine = "-------------------------";
        DrawLine(underLine, largefont, Offset, 30);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc;
        InsertItem(" Net. Total: ", order.Total.CValue, Offset);

        if (!order.Cash.Discount.IsZero())
        {
            Offset = Offset + smallinc;
            InsertItem(" Discount: ", order.Cash.Discount.CValue, Offset);
        }

        Offset = Offset + smallinc;
        InsertHeaderStyleItem(" Amount Payable: ", order.GrossTotal.CValue, Offset);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc;
        String address = shop.Address;
        DrawSimpleString("Address: " + address, minifont, Offset, 15);

        Offset = Offset + smallinc;
        String number = "Tel: " + shop.Phone1 + " - OR - " + shop.Phone2;
        DrawSimpleString(number, minifont, Offset, 35);

        Offset = Offset + 7;
        underLine = "-------------------------------------";
        DrawLine(underLine, largefont, Offset, 0);

        Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
        String greetings = "Thanks for visiting us.";
        DrawSimpleString(greetings, mediumfont, Offset, 28);

        Offset = Offset + mediuminc;
        underLine = "-------------------------------------";
        DrawLine(underLine, largefont, Offset, 0);

        Offset += (2 * mediuminc);
        string tip = "TIP: -----------------------------";
        InsertItem(tip, "", Offset);

        Offset = Offset + largeinc;
        string DrawnBy = "Meganos Softwares: 0312-0459491 - OR - 0321-6228321";
        DrawSimpleString(DrawnBy, minifont, Offset, 15);
    }
}
```

### [image]

### Some code to add the image has been commented here due to our requirements you can add can add your logo at header, as you can see in second image.

[image]

Comment: some item have multiple line like "Big Pizza @Discount has given by admin £2"
how to adjust now offset for other items or below details

Answer (score 1):

i am assuming you are not printing the output on a thermal printer but a normal high res bitmap capable printer? if so your problem basically requires you to generate a bitmap / pdf or some other graphics description that you can then send to the printer. as the example image you supplied just contains text then your task is simply to layout this text with coordinates and font sizes. the issue you will face, however is sourcing the right fonts and getting the spacing and the kerning etc absolutely right. this would be my starting point. see if you can find a font that looks like the one in the image. test it in photoshop / gimp or similar. make your photo of the termal print a background layer, then see if you can get the foreground to the be same. once you can copy it there, go and finish the software. pick the text coordinates from your photoshop mockup.

Comment: The font is not such important for me, my goals is to find best/ easiest way to write nice recipient for thermal printer,the problems that I have is in formatting/ arrange text into recipient , like setting paper size, arrange text  on left or right side  of paper, and so on ...

Comment: what's wrong with using the DrawString function in your example? are you having problems finding the correct coordinates for placing the text? if so i would experiment a bit to find the paper width

Comment: I think this is not best way ,but if you can prove that I will be very happy with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the receipt into BitMaps image and use XpsDocuentGenerator class. Or use open-source library like MigraDocs where you convert it into PDF and send to the Printers